# Auto Cancel Custom Notification using RemoteView

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a custom layout notification using remoteview. Problem I'm facing is, How to autoCancel the notification once the user touches it. 
I did try few things, but none is giving desired result.

Find Code below:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);      
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, RQST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNotification, pIntent);

    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContent(remoteView); 
    Notification notify = builder.build();
    notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notiManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notiManager.notify(NOTY_ID, notify);
```

Comment: You want to cancel the notification using remoteView or some button which is part of the view?

Comment: Yes..I mean there is a button on custom layout, that button I have set on  remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNotification, pIntent); But Intent Opens, the notification stays in notification bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I achieved this is by creating `BroadcastReceiver` which controls button clicks from `Notification`. Create something like this :

```
public class NotificationButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int action = intent.getIntExtra("mode", -1);
        switch (action) {
            // do some things depending on action if there are more stuff to do
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add your `BroadcastListener` to your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationButtonListener">
```

And you can create a helper class for creating and cancelling notification:

```
public class NotificationHelper {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 5;

    private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager = null;

    public static void showNotification(Context context) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_close, closePendingIntent);

        Intent mMainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        mMainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent mMainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 555, mMainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setTicker("Playing")
                .setContent(contentView)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_av_play)
                .setContentIntent(mMainPendingIntent);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

    public static void cancelNotification() {
        if (mNotificationManager != null) {
            mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        }
    }
}
```

And using that class in your `NotificationButtonListener` you can call `NotificationHelper.cancelNotification();` .

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I Changed PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 102, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); It worked :)

Answer (score 6):

For others who have a custom layout and want auto cancel to work,
If clicking anywhere on notification is ok, then don't use **remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent**. Because any view with **OnClick** Listener overrides the notification main **OnClick** Listener.

Use **setContentIntent** instead:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setContentTitle("title");
builder.setContentText("contect");
builder.setSmallIcon(@smallicon);
builder.setWhen(@when);
builder.setContent(remoteViews);
builder.setContentIntent(onClickPendingIntent); // use this
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```